# JavaScript Dom要素の無効化について

Tags: javascript

JavaScript初心者です。下記のHtml中にあるアラートを出すJavaScriptを無効にしたく、html中のheadに外部リソースとして、test.jsを作成しました。しかしながら、removeChildやdisabledを設定してもアラートが表示されます。アラート表示に限らずどのようにコードを書けばHtml中の任意のJavaScriptを無効にすることができるか教えて下さい。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">a</script>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('JavaScriptのアラート1');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('JavaScriptのアラート2');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var len = document.getElementsByTagName('script').length;
for (var i = 0; len > i; i++) {
    var target = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[i];
    document.write("<br>" + len + ":" + i + ":" + target.textContent + "</br>");
    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
}
```

また、test.jsの記述場所によって実行結果が変わる理由も教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: シチュエーションとしては昔のIEでできた[条件コンパイル](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc391875.aspx)のようなものを想定されているのでしょうか？ つまりデバッグ時には実行されたいが本番では削除したいというような。 そういう場合にはCでのプリプロセッサが使用出来るかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勉強になります。実際にやりたいことは、Webページ中の広告をブロックすることで、単にJavaScriptをオフにするとyoutubeなど広告でないものも使用できなくなるので、任意の要素だけを無効にできたらと思い、簡単な実験のため上記のコードで質問させて頂きました。

Comment: 自分でscriptを追加できることからブログなどのWEBサービスでのことかと思いますが、そのような場合広告を非表示にすることは利用規約違反になることがあります。単に自分のブラウザで閲覧時非表示にする場合は広告ブロック拡張機能やgreasemonkeyのようなものが使えるかもしれません。規約違反になるような質問の場合質問自体がこのサイトで利用規約違反の可能性があります。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY そのような質問自体がこのサイトの規約に反する、ということはないかと。例えばこういう話もありました。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1643/8000

Comment: @unarist  その[コメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1633/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AB%E6%84%8F%E5%9B%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%B1%E5%AE%B9%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B/1643#comment655_1643)にはそそれは「Stack Exchangeの利用規約に反します」とあるのでそういう場合もあるかと思いますけど。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 確かにそうですね…失礼しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` は、特に指定しない限りは同期的に実行されHTMLのパージングをブロックします。つまり、1つ目の `<script>` (test.js) を実行中には2番目と3番目の`<script>` は存在せず、`document.getElementsByTagName()` の結果にそれらが含まれません。

また、test.js を `alert()` の `<script>` より後に置くと、`alert()` は既に実行済みなので手遅れになります。

`<script>`を外から無効化する一般的な手法はないのではないかと思います。

`alert()` を消すのが目的であれば、test.js 内で `alert()` の定義を置き換えるのも手です。

test.js:

```
window.alert = console.log;
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。コメントでさらに質問して申し訳ないのですが、例えば、test.jsをアラートscriptの後ろに書いた場合は、getElementsByTagName()に引っかかってその回数for文が回ることを確認しました。しかしながら、実行後ということで、アラートは出ます。アラートに限らず、Html中の任意のJavaScriptを無効にするには、どのように記述したら良いでしょうか。

Comment: おそらく不可能です。回答に追記しました。